# Haskell - sth like for each loop

Tags: haskell, for-loop

i have for example three lists. Let's say 
[a,b,c], [d,e] and [f,g,h]
Now i want to generate all possibilities. The result has always the syntax of:
element from list1 + elem list2 + elem list3

For example: 
adf
aeg
cdf
bdf
bdg

and so on.

I have no idea at the moment. I want to use something like a for-each-loop but it did'nt work in haskell^^ Do you have some tipps for me to solve that problem?

Thanks!

Comment: `\xs ys zs -> [ (x,y,z) | x <- xs, y <- ys, z <- zs ]` or you can write it using map, which is like a for loop: `\xs ys zs -> concatMap (\x -> concatMap (\y -> map (\z -> (x,y,z)) zs) ys) xs`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way is to use list comprehensions as user2407038 has suggested

```
allCombinations1 xs ys zs = [(x, y, z) | x <- xs, y <- ys, z <- zs]
```

Equivalently, this list comprehension desugars into the monadic code

```
allCombinations2 xs ys zs = do
    x <- xs
    y <- ys
    z <- zs
    return (x, y, z)
```

Which is equivalent to using `liftM3` from `Control.Monad`:

```
allCombinations3 = liftM3 (\x y z -> (x, y, z))
```

You can also do much the same thing in an imperative style using `forM` and `concat`:

```
allCombinations4 xs ys zs = concat . concat . concat $
    forM xs $ \x ->
        forM ys $ \y ->
            forM zs $ \z ->
                return (x, y, z)
```

but this is probably slower, and is certainly not idiomatic Haskell code.  Alternatively, you can also use `sequence` for arbitrary numbers of inputs, which is certainly the most general and shortest:

```
allCombinations5 :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
allCombinations5 = sequence
```

To test them:

```
> allCombinations1 [1, 2] [3, 4] [5, 6]
[(1,3,5),(1,3,6),(1,4,5),(1,4,6),(2,3,5),(2,3,6),(2,4,5),(2,4,6)]
> allCombinations2 [1, 2] [3, 4] [5, 6]
[(1,3,5),(1,3,6),(1,4,5),(1,4,6),(2,3,5),(2,3,6),(2,4,5),(2,4,6)]
> allCombinations3 [1, 2] [3, 4] [5, 6]
[(1,3,5),(1,3,6),(1,4,5),(1,4,6),(2,3,5),(2,3,6),(2,4,5),(2,4,6)]
> allCombinations4 [1, 2] [3, 4] [5, 6]
[(1,3,5),(1,3,6),(1,4,5),(1,4,6),(2,3,5),(2,3,6),(2,4,5),(2,4,6)]
> allCombinations5 [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
[[1,3,5],[1,3,6],[1,4,5],[1,4,6],[2,3,5],[2,3,6],[2,4,5],[2,4,6]]
```

Note that the last one does not return a list of tuples but a list of lists, since it works for getting the difference combinations of N inputs, not a fixed number of inputs.

Like most things in Haskell, this problem can be solved a number of ways, I'm sure there are even others that could be added to this list.  Personally, I would recommend using `sequence` if you want arbitrary number of inputs, or the list comprehension form otherwise.  Both would be very readable and understandable to other Haskellers

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you for making me a better programmer.